# Which Spark.ML model is the same as a single node in a neural network?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, neural-network, apache-spark-ml

I'm experimenting with building a neural network by training one node at a time.  The intent is that if I assign a specific task to each of the nodes in the first hidden layer, I can train them individually, possibly even in parallel, and be able to say with certainty what each one does, and how it does it.  Then, I would run the data through the set of classifiers and save their output to make a new data set.  I then either build the output node as a classifier, or I repeat the process to build the next hidden layer.

I'm testing out the idea, to prove to myself that this will work, and measure its performance.  But I could really use a bit of help:

Is there a Spark.ML estimator/model that will work for this?  One that internally works in the same way that an individual neuron works in a neural network?

I've looked at LogisticRegression, thinking that it would work.  But it generates not one probability, but two, suggesting that internally it does not work the same.  I tried a LinearRegression, but that results in some negative values.  Is there a model that works, other than trying to train a neural network consisting of a single node?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. The most widely used transfer function for a neuron is the sigmoid function, which would be pretty much the same as the logistic regression.

Comment: So, internally, why is the raw prediction and the probability fields both vectors?

Comment: It's just a generalisation, as logistic regression can be applied to multiclass problems. In the case of binary labels one of the values is redundant as P(label=1) should be 1-P(label=0).